# How to fix npm vulnerabilities manually for node-fetch?

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

When I run npm install it says found 10 vulnerabilities (10 low)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details.

However, npm audit fix outputs up to date in 11s
fixed 0 of 10 vulnerabilities in 24653 scanned packages
10 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated

Does that review mean it is not supposed to be fixed by user?

When I run npm audit it gives me list of tables, similar to this:

```
=== npm audit security report ===                        
                                                                                
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                Manual Review                                 │
│            Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve            │
│                                                                              │
│         Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance          │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Denial of Service                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ node-fetch                                                   │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=2.6.1 <3.0.0-beta.1|| >= 3.0.0-beta.9                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ expo                                                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ expo > expo-constants > fbjs > isomorphic-fetch > node-fetch │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1556                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Denial of Service                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ node-fetch                                                   │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=2.6.1 <3.0.0-beta.1|| >= 3.0.0-beta.9                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ expo                                                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ expo > expo-linking > expo-constants > fbjs >                │
│               │ isomorphic-fetch > node-fetch                                │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1556                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Denial of Service                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ node-fetch                                                   │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=2.6.1 <3.0.0-beta.1|| >= 3.0.0-beta.9                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ expo                                                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ expo > expo-error-recovery > fbjs > isomorphic-fetch >       │
│               │ node-fetch                                                   │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1556                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

found 10 low severity vulnerabilities in 1062 scanned packages
  10 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.
chingun@Chinguns-MacBook-Pro rn-starter % npm install <node-fetch>@3.0.0-beta.9
zsh: no such file or directory: node-fetch
chingun@Chinguns-MacBook-Pro rn-starter % npm install node-fetch@3.0.0-beta.9
npm WARN fetch-blob@2.1.1 requires a peer of domexception@^2.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ node-fetch@3.0.0-beta.9
updated 1 package and audited 1062 packages in 4.161s

55 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 10 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
chingun@Chinguns-MacBook-Pro rn-starter % npm install node-fetch 3.0.0-beta.9
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/3.0.0-beta.9 - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '3.0.0-beta.9@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/chingun/.npm/_logs/2021-01-18T09_03_23_637Z-debug.log
chingun@Chinguns-MacBook-Pro rn-starter % npm install node-fetch 2.6.1
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/2.6.1 - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '2.6.1@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/chingun/.npm/_logs/2021-01-18T09_04_02_408Z-debug.log
chingun@Chinguns-MacBook-Pro rn-starter % npm install node-fetch@3.0.0-beta.9
npm WARN fetch-blob@2.1.1 requires a peer of domexception@^2.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ node-fetch@3.0.0-beta.9
updated 1 package and audited 1062 packages in 4.161s

55 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 10 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
chingun@Chinguns-MacBook-Pro rn-starter % npm audit fix
⸨  ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠧ loadDep:whatwg-fetch: sill install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTrnpm WARN fetch-blob@2.1.1 requires a peer of domexception@^2.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

up to date in 3.454s

55 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

fixed 0 of 10 vulnerabilities in 1062 scanned packages
  10 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated
chingun@Chinguns-MacBook-Pro rn-starter %
```

Comment: No, "require manual review" means you need to read and understand what the vulnerability is, and decide whether you can live with the risk or need to mitigate it. A DoS vulnerability would be harmless if you are running inside a private network of trusted users, but somewhere between a nuisance and a catastrophe on a public site, depending on your audience and risk profile.